# Creating default Object from empty value error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

down vote
i am getting the same error but this is my approah $rval = '4q34ipuipfpaidapdfadup'//a random number...

```
  $details = Company::with('User')->where('email', Input::get('qpass'))->first();

  $u = $details['user'];
  $u->reset_pass = $rval;     //then save to the database...
  $u->save();
```

i get an error saying " creating default object from empty value ", at this line $u->reset_pass = $rval; and when i broke the model down into seperate entities i still got the same error at that same line... i need assistance.. thanks.

```
  $rval = '4q34ipuipfpaidapdfadup'//a random number... 

  $details = Company::where('email', Input::get('qpass'))->first();
  $u = User::find($details->user_id)->get(); 
  $u->reset_pass = $rval;     //then save to the database...
  $u->save();
```

and i still get that error at this point ($u->reset_pass = $rval;

Comment: Can you print and post your $u value?

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
  $u = new User();
  $u = $u->find($details->user_id)->first(); 
  $u->reset_pass = $rval;     //then save to the database...
  $u->save();
```

also check if your user object is not empty by var_dump($u);

Comment: This: `find($details->user_id)->first()` will fail.

Comment: i was thinking the same thing, but this never crossed my mind. you initialize the User object, and you assign it a different user on the second line. from the second line it might produce the same result as i was getting.

Answer (score 0):

This error is returned when you try to write to an object property on an non-existent object.

Your **$u** variable is empty, that's why you're getting this error. Make sure that you fetch user correctly first - you can try **dd($u);** and see what it returns.

Comment: i did that and after dumping the output using dd($u) it returned a user object which was what i needed but now i did not understand the error, thats why i tried it in both ways.

Answer (score 0):

This: `$u = User::find($details->user_id)->get();` doesn't make sens. Yopu don't need to using `get` method. If you use `find` you will get the model so live it like this:

```
$u = User::find($details->user_id);
```